# NoLinkedYouTubeAccount error for comment upload

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I have a problem with the YouTube API V2.
I want to upload a comment to Youtube, but this error occurs:
    NoLinkedYouTubeAccount\n

## NoLinkedYouTubeAccount

### Error 401

I have searched on the internet, but the only reason I found is, that the account is not a YouTube account, but I have also used this account for liking some videos on YouTube,... ,so this should not be the reason. Her is my code for posting:

```
{
       string data = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                                <entry xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"" xmlns:yt=""http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"">
                                        <content>" + comment + "</content></entry>";


        HttpContent content = new StringContent(data);
        content.Headers.ContentLength = data.Length;
        content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/atom+xml");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToekn);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-GData-Key", "key=" + developer_key);


        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        string result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

The login works via OAuth2.0 and I get a authentication token and a refresh token correct. Has anyone an idea what the problem (or my fault) could be?